# Probability that the point randomly chosen in a triangle is closer to point B,than to other 2 points.

Tags: probability

We have a triangle ABC, where the length of AB is 12,length of BC is sqrt(116) and length of AC is sqrt(164). I need to find the probability that the point chosen inside that triangle is closer to point B than to other 2 points.

I put a point M on the middle of AB, and point N on the middle of BC, and I calculated the area of the triangle AMN.

Is my approach good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Generally speaking you need to calculate the quadrangle defined by B, the midpoint of side AB, the midpoint of side CB and the point where the two perpendicular bisectors of the sides AB and CB meet. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram . The probability is the area of that quadrangle divided through the area of the triangle.